# Java SAX read filename with metacharacters

Tags: java, sax, dom4j

How do you read files with metacharacters in the file name?
For example:

```
  private void readDoc (String path) { 
   try {  
       SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();   
       this.doc = reader.read("_40208#1159SOV.xml");
 } catch(Exception e) {
       this.print(e.getMessage()); } }
```

I tried using:

```
reader.read(Pattern.quote("_40208#1159SOV.xml");
```

but it doesn't work. Would like a solution that does not require renaming the files.
Thank you.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work," what does that mean? Can you produce a program's output?

Comment: it is just adding /Q and /E at file name path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`read`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#read%28java.lang.String%29) treats the system id as if it were a URL. `#` denotes an anchor in a URL so the method looks for a file named `_40208` which doesnt exist. You can encode the argument

```
Document doc = reader.read(URLEncoder.encode("_40208#1159SOV.xml", "UTF-8"));
```

> path to file's is getting from UI dialog (JFileChooser) which returns string

In this case the solution is even simpler: [`SAXReader` provides an overloaded method which uses a `File` reference](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

```
Document doc = reader.read(filechooser.getSelectedFile());
```

Comment: hmm now file name prints normal but SAX throws Exception that it couldn't find such file..may be something with charset i working on Windows and already try windows-1251 and windows-1252

Comment: Is the file on your application path?

Comment: No, path to file's is getting from UI dialog wich return string

Comment: @user1722669 then you'll need to supply the full path along with the filenane

Comment: Yes i understand that,i using such _40208#1159SOV.xml filename for example  my path string contain full path to file 
( someting like "C:\files\\_40208#1159SOV.xml" ) 
`reader.read(URLEncoder.encode(path, "UTF-8"))`; // throws exception 

`reader.read(path)`; //reading file if it'not containg metacharacters

Comment: By UI Dialog do you mean `JFileChooser`? If so the solution will be particularly simple. Please clarify this :)

Comment: Yes i mean JFileChooser.
I already find out were the problem was, in my case it was on path string construction i have something like that 
`String path = absolutePath + "\\" + fileName ;`
where absolutePath getting from JFileChooser and fileName getting throw `file(absolutPath).getFileList();` 
thank you for help i will accept this answer.But i will glad to see your solution with JFileChooser.

Answer (score 0):

I find more easy solution for this problem in my case 
`reader.read(new File(path));`
works perfect with out any URLEncoder.Hope it would help someone